# R Code error in matrix: 'dimnames' must be a list

Tags: r, statistics

I am currently using the Monte Carlo method [here](http://www.quantpsy.org/medmc/medmc.htm). 
Although the code (with some minor adaptations) worked with my 2x2 or 3x3 matrix, I keep getting the following error code for my 4x4 matrix:

> Error in matrix(c(0.0461705, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0028639, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0.0740766,  :  'dimnames' must be a list

What am I doing wrong and how do I address this error message?

```
################################################
# This code can be edited in this window and   #
# submitted to Rweb, or for faster performance #
# and a nicer looking histogram, submit        #
# directly to R.                               #
################################################
require(MASS)
a=1.1727132                       
b=0.2171818
c=1.3666784
d=0.1850852
rep=20000
conf=95
pest=c(a,b,c,d)
acov <- matrix(c(
0.0461705, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0.0028639, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0.0740766, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0.0013694
),4,4,4,4)
mcmc <- mvrnorm(rep,pest,acov,empirical=FALSE)
abcd <- mcmc[,1]*mcmc[,2]*mcmc[,3]*mcmc[,4]
low=(1-conf/100)/2
upp=((1-conf/100)/2)+(conf/100)
LL=quantile(abcd,low)
UL=quantile(abcd,upp)
LL4=format(LL,digits=4)
UL4=format(UL,digits=4)
################################################
# The number of columns in the histogram can   #
# be changed by replacing 'FD' below with      #
# an integer value.                            #
################################################
hist(abcd,breaks='FD',col='skyblue',xlab=paste(conf,'% Confidence Interval ','LL',LL4,'  UL',UL4),
main='Distribution of Indirect Effect')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Too many arguments to `matrix` : should be `matrix(c(...), 4,4)`

Answer (score 0):

As @Remko told, please specify the arguments correctly. The R matrix can be created as:

```
acov <- matrix(c(
0.0461705, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0.0028639, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0.0740766, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0.0013694
),nrow = 4, ncol = 4, byrow = T,dimnames = list(c("r","o","w","s"),c("c","o","l","s")))
```

You cans set byrow = F if you want the data to be arranged column wise. The length of rownames and colnames vector must match the number of rows and number of columns respectively.